# command to delete the space after user name in AD

Tags: windows, active-directory

What is the command to delete the space after user name in Active directory? User name craeted wrongly with space. Which needs to be delete now?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a lot but its not done with the script. I did it manually. Tried by changing display name, first name but no change in the distinguish name. I hope once an account been created, it will show the name (outside) where it will not change by script but we have press " F2 " and rename. I did by deleting the space manually by pressing " F2 " which worked. Thanks.